# Rails 5 email interceptor rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to prevent accidental emails to disabled users. And I figured the best way to do it would be to register mail interceptor, and hook into `delivering_email` method per this page https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

This is the code of my initializer (`config/initializers/email_interceptor.rb`) :

```
class EmailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    if User.where('email = ? AND disabled_at is not null', message.to).exists?
      message.perform_deliveries = false
    end
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(EmailInterceptor)
```

Then I'm trying to add tests to my app so I can make sure that users can register to begin with, and this is how that test looks like :

```
  let(:from) { 'a@foo.com' }
  let(:to) { 'b@foo.com' }
  subject { ActionMailer::Base.mail(to: to, from: from).deliver }

  it 'sends emails to non existing users' do
    expect { subject }.to change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count)
  end
```

There is an error that I get :

```
Failure/Error: subject { ActionMailer::Base.mail(to: to, from: from).deliver }

     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template action_mailer/base/mail with "mailer". Searched in:
         * "action_mailer/base"
     # ./spec/mailers/email_interceptor_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Am I doing something wrong here?** I am using rails `5.1.0` and I wonder if mailer api has changed or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your subject to :

```
subject do 
  ActionMailer::Base.mail(to: to, from: from, subject: 'test', body: 'test').deliver
end
```

No template used. There are other ways too, this seems to work for the problem what is described here.